# Detecting installed apps on iPhone with javascript or url

Tags: iphone, ios, safari

I am building a HTML5 based mobile web app for iPhone. I need to check whether user has specific application that I suggest. I heard that each iPhone application has unique URL scheme to detect their app indentity.

Therefore, I've read this article to get an idea.

[Is it possible to register a http+domain-based URL Scheme for iPhone apps, like YouTube and Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108693/is-it-possible-to-register-a-httpdomain-based-url-scheme-for-iphone-apps-like/1109200#1109200)

However, this is not perfect answer to make what I am trying to make.

here is what might happen

1. User clicks a recommendation app on mobile web browser.
2. Check with application iTunes URL and URL scheme.
3. If the user has the installed application, it returns 'installed'
   ==> In this case, the screen returns back to mobile browser.
4. If the user does not have the installed application, it returns 'uninstalled'
   ==> In this case, the screen moves to App Store.

I am running mobile web app with PHP language.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not possible I'm afraid. To be honest I'm glad, as there are real privacy concerns if any old web page can detect which apps I have installed.

That's definitely not a good thing!

UPDATE: If you're happy to go native, this library will do what you want.. http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/ihasapp

Answer (score 1):

If you know that a url scheme for the app exists then you can open it via a web link like this,  "myapp://".   With this there are some round about ways you can effectively check if a certain app exists.

See [this related stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5746289/determine-if-an-app-exists-and-launch-that-app-on-ios)

Comment: Wow, that's actually quite worrying. Good to know this technique exists though!

Comment: .. there's now a library to detect installed apps available on Cocoacontrols. I presume it uses the technique you've listed here. http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/ihasapp

Comment: haven't tried it, but couldn't you just fire off an XHR request (AJAX) to the registered url scheme (myapp://) and check the results. It may not work, but then again...

Comment: So it seems that XHR requests to an app url scheme always return nothing, guess I shouldn't be surprised.