# Check iOS application install or not from JavaScript

Tags: ios, installation

My requirement is to check if iOS application is installed on iOS device or not by JavaScript.

Is there any way to check this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if the app you want to check against has a custom URL scheme.

This answer even provides a javascript function:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7886755/1691231

Here is a list of custom URL schemes of popular apps: http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Registering_your_own_URL_schemes

And here is how you can implement a custom URL scheme if you are the developer of the app:
http://mobiledevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html

Comment: I have already done custom URL..
But if I want to check if application is installed in Iphone.

I want to check this by javascript.

Comment: Did you find the answer or not, I also want to do this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just to excute this script : ideviceinstaller -u "udid" -l will be list out all bundlesID in your phone
then compare it with your app "bundleId", if matched App had installed