# How to tell if an app is installed on an ios device using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, ios

Is there a method to determine in a web page if the device has a particular app installed?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, it would be a security risk but I might be wrong...

Comment: I seriously doubt it. This kind of access would be a security risk.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to do, there is a way. Check out [Launching an app with a custom url scheme](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html).

If you want to get your mobile browsers to download/use your application, you can set it up with a custom url scheme as detailed in that post. From safari, add a link to your app's custom url. If you get an error or aren't redirected when a link is clicked or triggered (which you can check for with a setTimeout()) Then the app is not installed.

I don't know what your use case is, so that's the best I can do.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to promote your app only if it isn't installed, you can add a meta tag to the page:

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=myAppStoreID, affiliate-data=myAffiliateData, app-argument=myURL">
```

For more information, see [Promoting Apps with Smart App Banners](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html) on Apple's developer website.

If that's not what you're trying to do, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5746289/determine-if-an-app-exists-and-launch-that-app-on-ios) may be helpful.