# Check if app is already installed on iOS from safari "Browser" using java script or any other way.

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cordova, safari

Check if app is already installed on iOS from safari "Browser" using java script or any other way.
 I need to check on my website weather my app is installed or not. If yes then I would like to open the app when somebody opens my website.

 I have the URL for my app to open.
Right now I have given two options on my website:
1) I have app installed will open the app
2) Available on the app store.

I want to decide at my side weather app is installed or not.
Using Any web technology.

Comment: check this other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5746289/determine-if-an-app-exists-and-launch-that-app-on-ios

Answer (score 3):

The new smart app banner feature in iOS 6 may cover what you are looking for.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html

Comment: That I have in my website, I wanted this for iOS less then 6.0