# launching an app with a URL

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios

I have a web-page which checks the user agent and redirects accordingly:

1. Opend the appstore to download the app for first time/open the app if app is already installed
2. Redirects to desktop site  for all other user agents

now the issue here is: if the app is deleted it throws error like  `error: page URI not supported`.

Ss there a way to check if the user has deleted the app?

PS(can only use javascript to do this).Thanks

Comment: Has anyone tried creating a new window for this?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5746289/determine-if-an-app-exists-and-launch-that-app-on-ios