# Launch game from iOS app and return to it once closed

Tags: ios, ios8

I have developed an app and I want to run another app installed on the phone and downloaded from the store (a game) inside a portion of the screen.

As I understood from my search, this is not possible. The next best solution would be to launch the game from my app and always return to it once the game closes.

I have been able to bootstrap a solution with a particular game using URL Schemes but is there a general solution working with any app downloaded from the store?

Do the answers provided there still apply or is it now possible? [Can you run an iOS app inside another iOS App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15627082/can-you-run-an-ios-app-inside-another-ios-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you still can not run an app within another app.

The only way to launch another app from your own is by using URL schemes, and there is no way to make a third-party app reopen your original app once the user completes a game.

You cannot directly obtain a list of installed applications to launch, but you could use [iHasApp](https://github.com/danielamitay/iHasApp) and possibly your own dataset of known URL schemes to check if a given app is installed on the device.