# Detect if application is installed on users Mac OS X from browser

Tags: macos, google-chrome, firefox, browser, safari

How can I detect from a browser if an application is installed on a users Mac OS X.

I want to achieve, that if the user clicks the download button then if he has the application installed it downloads a specific file which can be opened with this application, and if the user don't have the application, then he is prompted that he needs to download the application first to view the actual file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [link](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html) solved my question.

Thanks goes to Doug Stephen for providing the link, here:

[Determine if an app exists and launch that app on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5746289/determine-if-an-app-exists-and-launch-that-app-on-ios)

This [link](http://fredandrandall.com/blog/2011/07/30/how-to-launch-your-macios-app-with-a-custom-url/) was also helpful to move on with the parsing.

Comment: This was two years ago, but if I remember correctly even if these links are for iOS the content inside them helped and worked similar for OSX. Since I didn't get any answer I posted these links which helped me move towards my goal. If someone would post a better answer I would happily mark that as an answer.

Comment: @Gapp : The first link explains it for both OS X and iOS.