# Open app or App Store item in one link

Tags: ios, http

Is it a way to determine link for iOS that will open app if installed(preferably with custom url scheme) or this app in App Store otherwise?
There is a way to open app store like 
itms://
and app like
custom_scheme://

but is it any ability in iOS or other way around to do it in one link

for example

applnk://.../?params

will open app if installed and app store item of this app otherwise?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5746289/determine-if-an-app-exists-and-launch-that-app-on-ios 

Answer #2 seems to be exactly what you are looking for

Comment: seems so, thanks! looks like it's impossible to do without web and internet connection. well feature request to apple, for one more system scheme