# Is it possible to check if an app is installed in the device from browser?

Tags: ios, browser

I have an iOS app and website with same functionalities. I need to show like "Install myAppName in your iOS device" alert when opening my webpage if the app is not installed already and "Open it in myAppName" alert if the device has the app already installed. While clicking on alert should go to appstore or myApp respectively. Is it possible to know if my app is installed in the device from browser? Please help.

Comment: it may helps you [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5746289/determine-if-an-app-exists-and-launch-that-app-on-ios)

Comment: duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044805/how-to-check-if-an-app-is-installed-from-a-web-page-on-an-iphone